# Make FileInput Optional for user in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a file Input field in my form which works good to upload the file. But I want to keep the provision for user that they might not upload any file at all.

My Code looks like below -

Model Rule -

```
[['jha'],'file','skipOnEmpty' => true,'extensions' => 'pdf'],
```

Form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'jha')->fileInput(['accept' => 'application/pdf']); ?>
```

Controller -

```
public function actionCreatenewworkbasic()
    {


       $model = new Workpermit();
       $model->wp_timeissued = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

       if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 

       {

           $timenow = date('-Y-m-d-H-i-s');
           $model->jha = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'jha');
           $model->jha->saveAs('uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension);

           //save the path in the db

           $model->wp_jhaattach = 'uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension;

           $model->jha = null;
           $model->save(false);


           return $this->redirect(['availablework']); 
       }else{
            return $this->renderAjax('createnewworkbasic', [
               'model' => $model,
            ]);
       }      
    }
```

By this code, If I leave the upload field untouched, I get error -

```
Call to a member function saveAs() on null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `empty` before `saveAs()`

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    $timenow = date('-Y-m-d-H-i-s');
    $model->jha = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'jha');

    if (!empty($model->jha)) {
       $model->jha->saveAs('uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension);

       //save the path in the db

       $model->wp_jhaattach = 'uploads/jha/'.$model->jha->baseName.$timenow.'.'.$model->jha->extension;
    }

    $model->jha = null;
    $model->save(false);

    return $this->redirect(['availablework']);
}
```